Python Playwright export html file as single page PDF
I am using python playwright and I am currently opening a html file using the chromium browser. My goal is to export the exported the "rendered" file to a pdf with a single page containing the pages content using the Playwright Page PDF Api.
Currently I do the following things:

Opening Chromium Instance using playwright
Open page at html url
Getting the BoundingClientRect of the body
Passing height and width to pdf function of the playwright Page

The problem:
The little bit of content spills over to the next page. See: 
What I have tried:
I tried fiddling with the height and width. When adding a constant height more content is on the first page (but sometimes it still spills over). When using a big width the problem vanishes (but the pdf looks ugly). I think the line wrapping might be a problem because when not present there is no spilling.
Here is the code for a minimal reproduction of my problem:
import asyncio

from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.wait_for_timeout(100)
        await page.goto(
            'file:///path/to/file.html',
            wait_until='networkidle',
        )
        await page.wait_for_timeout(100)
        dimensions = await page.evaluate(
            """
        () => {
            const rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                "width": rect.width,
                "height": rect.height 
            }
        }
        """
        )
        await page.pdf(width=str(dimensions['width']), height=str(dimensions['height']), path='test.pdf')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Here is the link to a sample HTML I am using.

@KJ Thanks for your comment. The problem is that I specifically need a single page pdf file from a html regardless the length and formatting of the file. I am fine with providing a constant width but have a problem calculating the height of the page such that the content fits on one page.
